# Calling a function that returns Result<_,_> from a map method

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and I am struggling with optional URL parsing, I've got the following code:

```rust
use hyper::Uri;

fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    let url = Some("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

    let works = if let Some(url) = url {
        Some(parse_url(url)?)
    } else {
        None
    };

    let does_not = url.map(|u| parse_url(u)?);

    Ok(())
}

fn parse_url(url_str: &str) -> Result<Uri, String> {
    unimplemented!();
}
```

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8a7ef4f08e81ec9f2b16dda0c5e38260)

Documentation says that calling `?` can be used as a syntactic sugar to simplify error handling.

So what bothers me is that I can perfectly fine map the inner value of `Option<T>` manually, using `if let` syntax and return early from the method but cannot just `.map()` the inner value of `Option<T>`.

So my question is actually how can I easily `parse` an optional value by avoiding if/else conditions in Rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?` handles errors in the current function. When you call `map`, you create a closure (using `|_|`), which is a different function.

You'd have to use `?` outside of that closure:

```rust
let does_not = url.map(|u| parse_url(u))?;
```

Unfortunately, this won't quite work as at this point you have a `Option<Result<_, _>>` rather than a `Result<Option<T>, _>`. You can fix that using [`transpose`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.transpose):

```rust
let does_not = url.map(|u| parse_url(u)).transpose()?;
```

[(Permalink to the playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=547dc2e1c72e22c304db4caac739a9b4)